# Asymmetric list of tables

Tags: r

I have a `list` of `tables` where each table has the same number of rows but a different number of columns. For each `table`, I am calculating mean of each column and multiply it by the sum of that column.

This gives me a new row for each `table` in the `list` (one value for each column in each `table`). Then I need to sum up values of each new row and divide it by the sum of column values. I can do it like this:

```
# calculate mean and sum for each column in the list of tables
  myfun <- function(x){
    return(mean(x) * sum(x)) #mean of a column * sum of the same column
  }
  es  <- lapply(LIST.OF.TABLES, function(x){apply(x,2,myfun)})
  es  <- sapply((es), sum)/sapply(LIST.OF.TABLES, sum)
```

It works but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Reproducible example is needed here. Ps. assymetrric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can revert to the `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
list_of_tables <- list(mtcars, ChickWeight %>% mutate_all(as.numeric))

## loop through all tables
(ret <- map_dbl(list_of_tables,
  ## for each table calculate your statistic on numeric columns
  ~ .x %>% 
     summarise_all(~ mean(.x) * sum(.x)) %>%
     ## transform to long format
     gather(column, value) %>%
     ## summarise the results
     summarise(result = sum(value) / sum(.x)) %>%
     ## return the result as vector
     pull(result)
))

# [1] 173.41411  97.18084
```

The result is maybe not *better*  but for sure more readable and it is a well invested time to learn the grammar of the `tidyverse`, IMHO.

---

This is indeed the same result as your code:

```
LIST.OF.TABLES <- list_of_tables
es  <- lapply(LIST.OF.TABLES, function(x){apply(x,2,myfun)})
sapply((es), sum)/sapply(LIST.OF.TABLES, sum)
# [1] 173.41411  97.18084
```